# How to use Oracle Complex Type out parameter in .NET

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle

I have an Oracle procedure that passes a complex type as an out parameter that I need to be able to use within .NET.  I have not had much luck finding a good example of how to make something like this work so I am hoping some here might have the answer or have done this.

Oracle.manageddataAccess.dll version#  4.121.1.0

Code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE APPS.gary_pol_tbl_type AS TABLE OF gary_pol_rec_type;


    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPS.gary_pol_test3 ( x_gary_pol IN OUT apps.gary_pol_tbl_type ) AS
   CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT org_id,
               po_type,
               po_header_id,
               po_num,
               po_release_id,
               po_release_num,
               vendor_id,
               vendor_name,
               vendor_site_num,
               vendor_site_name,
               pay_site_id,
               currency_code,
               po_amount,
               po_date,
               buyer_name,
               shipment_num,
               po_line_id,
               line_num,
               po_creation_date,
               release_date,
               item_num,
               item_description,
               uom,
               po_qty,
               received_qty,
               unit_price,
               taxable_flag,
               closed_date,
               entity,
               branch,
               planner_name,
               attribute1,
               attribute2,
               batch_number,
               processed_flag,
               wm_uuid,
               creation_date,
               created_by,
               last_update_date,
               last_updated_by
          FROM xxit.xxfin_ap_imagenow_pol_out
         WHERE ROWNUM < 2001
      ORDER BY org_id ASC NULLS LAST,
               po_header_id ASC NULLS LAST,
               po_release_id ASC NULLS LAST,
               shipment_num ASC NULLS LAST,
               po_line_id ASC NULLS LAST,
               line_num ASC NULLS LAST;
BEGIN
   FOR c1_rec IN c1 LOOP
      x_gary_pol.EXTEND;
      x_gary_pol ( x_gary_pol.LAST ) :=
         apps.gary_pol_rec_type ( c1_rec.org_id,
                                  c1_rec.po_type,
                                  c1_rec.po_header_id,
                                  c1_rec.po_num,
                                  c1_rec.po_release_id,
                                  c1_rec.po_release_num,
                                  c1_rec.vendor_id,
                                  c1_rec.vendor_name,
                                  c1_rec.vendor_site_num,
                                  c1_rec.vendor_site_name,
                                  c1_rec.pay_site_id,
                                  c1_rec.currency_code,
                                  c1_rec.po_amount,
                                  c1_rec.po_date,
                                  c1_rec.buyer_name,
                                  c1_rec.shipment_num,
                                  c1_rec.po_line_id,
                                  c1_rec.line_num,
                                  c1_rec.po_creation_date,
                                  c1_rec.release_date,
                                  c1_rec.item_num,
                                  c1_rec.item_description,
                                  c1_rec.uom,
                                  c1_rec.po_qty,
                                  c1_rec.received_qty,
                                  c1_rec.unit_price,
                                  c1_rec.taxable_flag,
                                  c1_rec.closed_date,
                                  c1_rec.entity,
                                  c1_rec.branch,
                                  c1_rec.planner_name,
                                  c1_rec.attribute1,
                                  c1_rec.attribute2,
                                  c1_rec.batch_number,
                                  c1_rec.processed_flag,
                                  c1_rec.wm_uuid,
                                  c1_rec.creation_date,
                                  c1_rec.created_by,
                                  c1_rec.last_update_date,
                                  c1_rec.last_updated_by );
   END LOOP;
 apps.gary_pol_tbl_type ) );
END gary_pol_test3;
```

I have seen some references in the searching i have done by setting the oracleDBType.... to an object or array but i don't have those options. I could see where the object might be what I am looking for.

Here is my code in c# that is trying to read this.

```
public static DataTable test2()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                using (OracleConnection cn = BSIC_DAL.OracleHelpers.createOracleConnection())
                {
                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = cn;

                    cmd.CommandText = "apps.gary_pol_test3";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    //cmd.Parameters.Add("p_batch_number", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 133;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("x_gary_pol", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

how do i consume an oracle complex type like the above in .Net?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply return a RefCursor?

Should be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APPS.gary_pol_test3 ( x_gary_pol OUT SYS_REFCORSOR) AS

begin
   open x_gary_pol for
   SELECT org_id, po_type, po_header_id, ...
   FROM xxit.xxfin_ap_imagenow_pol_out
   WHERE ROWNUM < 2001
   ORDER BY org_id ASC NULLS LAST, ...
end;
```

In C# it should be like this one (not verified):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("x_gary_pol", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Funny you mention that as I thought the same thing and did get this to work as you suggest.  However, our db figured it doubled the time so simply thought I would see if it was possible and if so how?  Is this how you normally do it?

Comment: Yes, in my application **each** data is provided as RefCursor (as long as it is not a single value only). Some are passed to a OracleDataAdapter and some are passed to an OracleDataReader, depends where the data is used at client code.